How to pass the component as a component prop in Qwik
In react we can pass the component as a component property. For example

Link to the codesandbox.

interface IButtonProps {
  icon?: React.ComponentType;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

const Button = ({ icon: Icon, children }: IButtonProps) => (
  <button>
    {Icon && <Icon />}
    {children}
  </button>
);

const DotIcon = (props) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      fill="currentColor"
      width="24"
      height="24"
      {...props}
    >
      <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="5" />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Button icon={DotIcon}>Example button</Button>;
}


I notice the PropFunction<(value: T) => void> trick for callbacks but how do I pass the component as a prop exactly?
Important! I am using the Qwik framework, not a react

not sure if you are still need an answer, but it really depends.
If you want to have a custom icon in the button which is optional.
Use a named slot.
export const Button = component$(() => {
  return (
    <button>
      <Slot name="icon" />
      <Slot />
    </button>
  );
});

export const Usage = component$(() => {
  return (
    <Button>
      <Icon name="something" q:slot="icon" />
      Launch
    </Button>
  );
});


You could also pass a render function, but than you're exploiting qwiks amazing optimization and child and parent won't be decoupled anymore.
